# Change object's class

Tags: python, class

In a chess game, I define `p1 = Pawn()`.

I'd like to be able to promote it:

```
def promote(self, piece):
        pos = f'{Config.tile_convert(self.x)}{Config.tile_convert(self.y, True)}'
        try:
            self = piece(pos, color=self.color, num='s')
        except NameError:
            print(f'Cannot promote {self.pieceid} to {piece}')
```

However, feeding in `Queen` or `Bishop` doesn't actually change the object from being a `Pawn`. I think it's because of scoping:

```
class Chesspiece:
...

class Pawn(ChessPiece):
    def promote()
    ...

class Queen(Chesspiece):
...
```

How can I change the class of an object?

Comment: You can't do it from an instance method, you can only replace the entire object "from outside"

Comment: You can't, but you can assign to your board a new object `Queen()` at the same location belonging to the same player. and remove the old instance of `Pawn`

Comment: Just like in real chess, you don't actually change your pawn *into* another piece; you remove it from the board and put a *new* piece in its place. A pawn doesn't promote itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassigning any bare name (including `self`) *rebinds* the name; whatever was in there before is thrown away, and the name now points to something unrelated.

So when you do:

```
self = piece(pos, color=self.color, num='s')
```

you just lose access to the "real" `self` (the object the method was called on), you don't *change* the object it was called on.

The only way to do what you want is kinda hacky; to reassign `__class__` on `self` (and change any other attributes needed to make it a valid instance of the new class).

So in this case, you might be able to just do:

```
self.__class__ = piece
```

and if attribute values might need to be recreated/revalidated, or `piece` might be a factory function or weirdo class whose `__new__` doesn't necessarily return the type it was called on, you'd create a new piece as a template, then copy from it, like so:

```
# Make a new piece to copy from
newpiece = piece(pos, color=self.color, num='s')

vars(self).clear()                 # Clear out existing attributes
vars(self).update(vars(newpiece))  # Copy attributes from new piece
self.__class__ = newpiece.__class__ # Using newpiece.__class__ ensures it's the resulting class
                                    # in case of factory functions, weird __new__, etc.
```

Note: This is *usually* **not** what you want to do. As [Rocky Li mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856272/change-objects-class/55856471#comment98373936_55856272), the usual approach is to replace the object in whatever structure holds it, rather than updating the class in place on an existing object, e.g. if you have variable named `board` which is a 2D list of lists, you'd just do:

```
a_piece = ...  # Piece to replace
new_piece_type = ...  # Type of piece it's being replaced with
pos = f'{Config.tile_convert(a_piece.x)}{Config.tile_convert(a_piece.y, True)}'

# Replace entire object (and local alias name) at known coordinates with new object
board[a_piece.x][a_piece.y] = a_piece = new_piece_type(pos, color=a_piece.color, num='s')
```

Comment: Using the second approach, is the new piece remapped to the same variable?

Comment: @alec_a: By "second approach", you mean the "reassign within `board`" solution? If you notice, I assign the new object to both `board[a_piece.x][a_piece.y]` and `a_piece`, so the local alias is updated to refer to the new piece too. If this is in a function and the caller provided `a_piece`, it won't change the *caller's* reference though, but in that case, just change the contract with the caller; instead of claiming to update the provided argument in place, *return* the new object, and the caller can do: `a_piece = promote(a_piece, new_piece_type)` or whatever.

Comment: In my case, `a_piece` is simply `self`. I'm not sure how to use the specific variable

Comment: Any number of variables could be getting replaced based on which pawn is promoted

Comment: @alec_a: To be clear, if the caller did `some_piece.promote(...)`, their `some_piece` won't change in the "better" solution. You'd have to have `promote` return the new piece, and the caller would have to do `some_piece = some_piece.promote(...)`, unless the caller themselves was reliably referencing the pieces via the global `board` (in which case the reassignment in `board` would change what the caller sees the next time they look up that index in `board`).